# Calling subclass method from contructor of superclass

Tags: php

How Can i call subclass method from superclass constructor?

Example subclass:

```
<?php
include('../classes/A.php');

class B extends A {
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->view);
    }
    public function view() {
        //something
    }
}

$b = new B;

?>
```

Example superclass:

```
<?php
abstract class A
{
    private $callback;

    public function __construct($callback)
    {
        $this->callback = $callback;

        call_user_func($this->callback);
    }   
}
?>
```

What can I do to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an array containing your object instance `$this`, and the method to call

(see Example #4 of the [`call_user_func` man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) on calling class methods)

```
class B extends A {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(array($this, 'view'));
    }
    public function view() {
        //something
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it in a moment :)